# Checkbox is not being validated in form wizard

Tags: jquery, jquery-form-wizard

I have a form wizard and I want to use checkboxes. The problem is when I make a checkbox required it is not recognized by the wizard so it will go to the next step/tab even if the checkbox is not checked. On the last step it shows that a field is still required (the checkbox that wasn't checked). It works fine with regular inputs like text, number, select.

UPDATE: added code snippet and it works here. Maybe I'm using a wrong jquery version?

```js
$(".wizard-horizontal").steps({
  headerTag: "h6",
  bodyTag: "fieldset",
  transitionEffect: "fade",
  titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#',
  labels: {
    finish: 'Submit'
  },
  onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
    alert("Form submitted.");
  }
});
//        vertical Wizard       //
// ------------------------------
$(".wizard-vertical").steps({
  headerTag: "h3",
  bodyTag: "fieldset",
  transitionEffect: "fade",
  enableAllSteps: true,
  stepsOrientation: "vertical",
  labels: {
    finish: 'Submit'
  },
  onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
    alert("Form submitted.");
  }
});


//       Validate steps wizard //
// -----------------------------
// Show form
var stepsValidation = $(".wizard-validation");
var form = stepsValidation.show();

stepsValidation.steps({
  headerTag: "h6",
  bodyTag: "fieldset",
  transitionEffect: "fade",
  titleTemplate: '<span class="step">#index#</span> #title#',
  labels: {
    finish: 'Submit'
  },
  onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
    if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
      return true;
    }
    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
    return form.valid();
  },
  onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
    return form.valid();
  },
  onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
    alert("Submitted!");
  }
});

// Initialize validation
stepsValidation.validate({
  ignore: 'input[type=hidden]', // ignore hidden fields
  errorClass: 'danger',
  successClass: 'success',
  highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
  },
  unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
  },
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
  },
  rules: {
    email: {
      email: true
    }
  }
});
// live Icon color change on state change
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".current").find(".step-icon").addClass("bx bx-time-five");
  $(".current").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#5A8DEE'
  });
});
// Icon change on state
// if click on next button icon change
$(".actions [href='#next']").click(function () {
  $(".done").find(".step-icon").removeClass("bx bx-time-five").addClass("bx bx-check-circle");
  $(".current").find(".step-icon").removeClass("bx bx-check-circle").addClass("bx bx-time-five");
  // live icon color change on next button's on click
  $(".current").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#5A8DEE'
  });
  $(".current").prev("li").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#39DA8A'
  });
});
$(".actions [href='#previous']").click(function () {
  // live icon color change on next button's on click
  $(".current").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#5A8DEE'
  });
  $(".current").next("li").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#adb5bd'
  });
});
// if click on  submit   button icon change
$(".actions [href='#finish']").click(function () {
  $(".done").find(".step-icon").removeClass("bx-time-five").addClass("bx bx-check-circle");
  $(".last.current.done").find(".fonticon-wrap .livicon-evo").updateLiviconEvo({
    strokeColor: '#39DA8A'
  });
});
// add primary btn class
$('.actions a[role="menuitem"]').addClass("btn btn-primary");
$('.icon-tab [role="menuitem"]').addClass("glow ");
$('.wizard-vertical [role="menuitem"]').removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-light-primary");
```

```html
<link href="https://intermissions.tech/origin/app-assets/css/plugins/forms/wizard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://intermissions.tech/origin/app-assets/vendors/js/forms/validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://intermissions.tech/origin/app-assets/vendors/js/extensions/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<section id="validation">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header pb-0">
                                            <h4 class="card-title">Conference registration</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-content">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <form action="#" class="wizard-validation">
                                                    <!-- Step 1 -->
                                                    <h6>
                                                        <i class="step-icon"></i>
                                                        <span>Legal Affirmation</span>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <!-- Step 1 -->
                                                    <!-- body content of step 1 -->
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                   <fieldset>
                                                                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-glow">
                                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="confirm_english" name="test" required>
                                                                            <label for="confirm_english">my checkbox</label>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </fieldset>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="lastName3">Last Name</label>
                                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName3" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" required>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                    <!-- body content of step 1 end -->
                                                    <!-- Step 2 -->
                                                    <h6>
                                                        <i class="step-icon"></i>
                                                        <span>Attendence and Services</span>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <!-- step 2 -->
                                                    <!-- body content of step 2 end -->
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                       
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                    <!-- body content of step 2 end -->
                                                    <!-- Step 3 -->
                                                    <h6>
                                                        <i class="step-icon"></i>
                                                        <span>Conference Payment</span>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <!-- step 3 end -->
                                                    <!-- step 3 content -->
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <label for="eventStatus3">Event Status</label>
                                                                    <select class="custom-select form-control required" id="eventStatus3" name="eventStatus">
                                                                        <option></option>
                                                                        <option value="Planning">Planning</option>
                                                                        <option value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
                                                                        <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                    <!-- step 3 content end-->
                                                    <!-- Step 4 -->
                                                    <h6>
                                                        <i class="step-icon"></i>
                                                        <span>Payment Confirmation</span>
                                                    </h6>
                                                    <!-- step 4 end -->
                                                    <!-- step 4 content -->
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                        
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                    <!-- step 4 content end-->
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a formatted [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I added the code snippet and it works here for reason, could it be a that the jquery version I'm using is wrong? I included 3.3.1 here

Comment: You would get console errors before if that is the case

Comment: Maybe it's another JS file is conflicting with the wizard.

Comment: Code sample seems to work properly!! do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi I know it worked here fine, so I'm looking at the other JS files if there is something that is interfering that makes it not work. I don't get console errors.

Comment: @JavierOlayo Can you refer to us what javascript files and libraries are you including in your page?

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi I actually found out that I have this in my css 
`.checkbox input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}`
And for some reason that makes the form wizard ignore the checkbox, so I wonder if I have to change my CSS file o the form wizard rules?

Comment: @JavierOlayo I think maybe this has to do with their JS code, as if you notice that they are checking for elements visibility, feel free to check if this is the cause or not